# How to reflect text from a text box to a datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, reflection, datagrid

How can i write a program that reflects a text that is in a text box to a data grid? Ex: You write something in a textbox (textBoxURL.Text) and it automatically reflects the text to a datagrid (row.URL).

Here is a piece of my code:

```
DsVersions.ASSEMBLY2Row row = dsVersions.ASSEMBLY2.NewASSEMBLY2Row();
row.URL = textBoxURL.Text;
```

If any question (Not clear, not enough detail, more code, confusing) please comment.

Comment: @Chris From a textbox.Text into a Datagrid in the program(Windows Form), I don't think i quite get you...

Comment: rephrase your question especially in regards to the term "reflect" what are you actually trying to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void textBoxURL_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (DsVersions.ASSEMBLY2Row row in dsVersions.ASSEMBLY2.Rows)
            {
                row.URL = textBoxURL.Text;
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Give that a try...

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little simple, but I'll throw this out there.

On the `keypress` or `keydown` event for the text box, change the value in the data grid(cell I'm guessing) to the `textbox.text`.